# How to share a configuration across multiple OSGI services in AEM

Tags: osgi, aem

In AEM, I need to configure a list of strings and share it across multiple services. What is the best way to accomplish this? The list needs to be configurable at run time.

Comment: have you seen this? http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2015/10/updating-osgi-configurations-in-aem-and-sling. OSGI service to read write OSGI configurations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a dedicated configuration service that you configure and that is referenced by all other OSGi services that require one or more of the configured values.

Example configuration service

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.commons.osgi.PropertiesUtil;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;

@Service(ConfigurationService.class)
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
public class ConfigurationService {

    @Property
    private static final String CONF_VALUE1 = "configuration.value1";
    private String value1;

    @Property
    private static final String CONF_VALUE2 = "configuration.value2";
    private String value2;

    @Activate
    public void activate(final ComponentContext componentContext) {
        this.value1 = PropertiesUtil.toString(componentContext.get(CONF_VALUE1), "");
        this.value2 = PropertiesUtil.toString(componentContext.get(CONF_VALUE2), "");
    }

    public String getValue1() {
        return this.value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return this.value2;
    }
}
```

This is the bare minimum of such a class. But it will create a configurable OSGi service that you can configure in Apache Felix Configuration Manager (`/system/console/configMgr`).

Note: It is important to use `metatype = true` in the `@Component` annotation.

The next step is to reference this service in the "consuming" services.

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;

@Service(MyService.class)
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = true)
public class MyService {

    @Reference
    private ConfigurationService configurationService;

    @Activate
    public void activate(final ComponentContext componentContext) {
        this.configurationService.getValue1();
    }
}
```

Note: This example uses the Apache SCR annotations which can be used with AEM out of the box. You can learn more about SCR annotations used in this example (`@Service`, `@Component`, `@Property`, `@Reference`) in the official documentation: [Apache Felix SCR Annotation Documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html)

Comment: pretty neat explanation. But, shouldnt we use an interface here? and the implementing in a class, and declaring the interface as a service. That seems secure enough.

Comment: @theanubhava As I noted in my text: This is the bare minimum. Obviously there are a lot of things you can improve here. For the sake of brevity I chose the shortest possible example to demonstrate the basic principle. Usually, you would use interfaces and split them up in a `api` and `impl` bundle etc.

Comment: The other thing that could be useful on this topic is discussed in http://blog.vogella.com/2016/09/26/configuring-osgi-declarative-services/ which is to add configurationPid=com.package. ConfigurationService inside the @Component of the consuming service.

Comment: Why does MyService class not just use configurationService.getValue1() when it needs it?  Why dies it need its own Activate?  What does meta do in both classes?